# Masonry Layout: prevent div from breaking up or being cut

Tags: html, css

My React code is as follows:

```
<div className="gridlist">
      <div className="card">
        {shops.map((shop) => (
          <MediaCard
            card={shop}
            bname={shop.bname}
            description={shop.description}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
</div>
```

The `{shops.map((shop) => (` part is just getting the information from a database I made which I want to display in CSS masonry format. The MediaCard component is just a component I made that holds some information, such as the title, description, image, etc.

My CSS code:

```
/* The Masonry Container */
.gridlist {
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  max-width: 768px;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  row-gap: 1.5em;
}

/* The Masonry Brick */
.card {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* Masonry on large screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .gridlist {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

/* Masonry on medium-sized screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .gridlist {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

/* Masonry on small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 540px) {
  .gridlist {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

The problem is this:

[image]

As you can see, a box is being cut off. So how would I fix this?

Comment: Not a react issue i'm removing the tag, Also try add a working code snippet illustrating the issue so it's easy for people to help you.

Comment: I think this will help since it looks like a columnbreak issue: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-prevent-column-break-within-an-element/

Comment: @Rmaxx, thanks, but I tried that approach and it only just made each block one top of the other.

Comment: @Rmaxx, I changed some other styling and then tried that, and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some time I finally found out the solution. I changed my `.gridlist` className style to this:

```
.gridlist {
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  columns: 4;
  column-gap: 40px;
}
```

I also changed the `.card` className styles to this:

```
.card {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

And for my MediaCard component, I added a className of `.MediaCard`. Then I added this to my CSS:

```
.MediaCard {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Finally, I added some responsive styling:

```
@media (max-width: 1650px) {
  .gridlist {
    columns: 3;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .gridlist {
    columns: 2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .gridlist {
    columns: 1;
  }
}
```

However, I still do not know the problem I had with my previous code. If anyone can tell me, thanks!